# How to handle OR operator between STRING expressions inside parenthesis with PLY

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex, lexer, ply

I want to interpret sentences like:

```
 "i + want + to + turn + ( on | off ) + the + lights"
```

to get sentences like:

```
  "i want to turn on the lights"

  "i want to turn off the lights"
```

I try defining a lexer and a parser to help me dealing with that but
I don't know how to handle the expresion between parenthesis that has 
and "**OR**" operator that give like valid values one or the other expressions beside 
the pipe (|) character.

Grammar rule '+' (PLUS) in this case of STRINGs, is a concat operation.

```
def p_expression_plus(p):
     'expression : expression PLUS term'
     p[0] = p[1] + ' ' + p[3]
```

But I don't know how to define the **OR** operation and obtain the addition of the two strings between parenthesis in a separate way like I defined above.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is really a parsing question, since parsing of your expressions is straight-forward. Although you don't show your attempt, what you do show is sufficient to suggest that you know how to do it. So I'm assuming that your question is really, "How do I evaluate an expression which could return multiple strings?"

The simple solution would seem to be to evaluate the expression as a list of possible strings. If you had a lot of alternatives, that would result in a very large array, but it's otherwise straight-forward. The basic idea is encapsulated by this simple class:

```py
class StrExpr(object):
  def __init__(self, str=None, *args):
    '''Make a StrExpr from a single string and/or one or more iterators'''        
    self.alts = [str] if str is not None else []
    for arg in args: self.alts.extend(arg)

  def __add__(self, other):
    '''Return a new StrExpr from this one concatenated with another one'''
    if not isinstance(other, StrExpr): return NotImplemented
    return StrExpr(None, (l + ' ' + r for l in self.alts for r in other.alts))

  def __or__(self, other):
    '''Return a new StrExpr containing alternatives from this
       one and another one.
    '''
    if not isinstance(other, StrExpr): return NotImplemented
    return StrExpr(None, self.alts, other.alts)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.alts)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "StrExpr"+str(self.alts)
```

Quick test:

```
>>> a = ( StrExpr("i") + StrExpr("want") + StrExpr("to") + StrExpr("turn")
...     + (StrExpr("on") | StrExpr("off")) + StrExpr("the") + StrExpr("lights")
...     + (StrExpr("now") | StrExpr("later") | StrExpr("tomorrow"))
...     )
>>> a
StrExpr['i want to turn on the lights now', 'i want to turn on the lights later', 'i want to turn on the lights tomorrow', 'i want to turn off the lights now', 'i want to turn off the lights later', 'i want to turn off the lights tomorrow']
>>> print('\n'.join(a.alts))
i want to turn on the lights now
i want to turn on the lights later
i want to turn on the lights tomorrow
i want to turn off the lights now
i want to turn off the lights later
i want to turn off the lights tomorrow
```

A more Pythonic solution would be to make the `StrExpr` a generator which lazily produces its alternatives. But the principle is similar.

Comment: i didn't sure about if lexers and parsers were the right tools to use.
I appreciate your advice and I will take that path.
I read some of your answers before post first and i am grateful that you share your knowleges here.  Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!